# Rendering Problems Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio 1.5.1  &  Java SE Development Kit v7 Update.80.x64

But When I Create New Project This Error Displayed In ide :

```
   Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)
 Tip: Try to build the project.  The surrounding layout (@layout/activity_main) did not actually include this layout. Remove tools:showIn=... from the root tag.
```

I also switched to Java.SE.Development.Kit.v8.Update.74.x64 and tried all stackoverflow q2a

my android studio haved api 23 by default but i also downloaded api 14 , 15 , ........ , 22 and try all of them and rebuild project but nothing changed !!!

i am beginner in java and android and started it from Udemy.The.Complete.Android.Developer.Course

Comment: Did you add dependencies to the support library to your gradle build file?

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}

Answer (score 7):

Do exactly as the instruction says. Remove the line

```
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
```

problem solved.  The newer release of Android must include this line as part of the template, but apparently conflicts with CoordinatorLayout tag used in the demo (guess on my part)

Answer (score 0):

Main activity must also know that content_detail layout is included in it.
Add following code in layout  acitvity_main

```
<include layout="@layout/content_detail" />
```